# implementing sound into a java game

Tags: java, audio

I've followed Buckys java game development with slick for the basic setup for the game and since then I've taken it into my own hands. Currently I'm just building the menu and its pretty much finished except i want to add sound to it. I've been stuck on this for a week so its not like i haven't done any research for this, i just can't make it work. Now I've found some code to do this which seems to make sense, how could i implement this or if you have a better idea for how to add some sound, appreciated.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

static String soundtrack = "res/doxx.wav";

public void sound(String path){

    try{
        AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Menu.class.getResource(path));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("check "+path+"\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

edit: This code has been taken out of the program now, but feel free to post answers based on it

That's the code related to adding sound so far, here is the entirety of my menu class, its not to huge. To be honest you probably don't need to look at it in detail, its currently all based around graphics and two buttons (start and quit) which are spinning.

```
package javagame;

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;


public class Menu extends BasicGameState {

double pi=3.14159265359;
float beanPosY = 330;
float beanPosX = 70;
double gravity = 0.01;
double angleStart=1.5*pi;
double angleQuit=0.5*pi;
int radius=120;
int centerX=300;
int centerY=160;
float startPosX = (float) (centerX + Math.sin(angleStart)*radius);
float startPosY = (float) (centerY + Math.cos(angleStart)*radius);
float quitPosX = (float) (centerX + Math.sin(angleQuit)*radius);
float quitPosY = (float) (centerY + Math.cos(angleQuit)*radius);
double force = 0;
public Menu(int state){
}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
    Sound music = new Sound();
    music.playBackGround("res/doxx.wav");
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{     
    Image background = new Image("res/background640x480.fw.png");
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0);

    Image start = new Image("res/Start100x100.fw.png");
    Image quit = new Image("res/quit100x100.fw.png");
    start.draw(startPosX,startPosY);
    quit.draw(quitPosX,quitPosY);

    Image grass = new Image("res/grass640x150.fw.png");
    g.drawImage(grass,0,340);

    Image bean = new Image("res/bean.jpg");
    bean.draw(beanPosX, beanPosY);
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
    int posX = Mouse.getX();
    int posY = Mouse.getY();
    double constant=0.002*pi;

    startPosX = (float) (centerX + Math.sin(angleStart)*radius);
    startPosY = (float) (centerY + Math.cos(angleStart)*radius);
    quitPosX = (float) (centerX + Math.sin(angleQuit)*radius);
    quitPosY = (float) (centerY + Math.cos(angleQuit)*radius);

    angleStart+=constant;
    angleQuit+=constant;
    if (angleStart>=2*pi){
        angleStart-=2*pi;
    }
    if (angleQuit>=2*pi){
        angleQuit-=2*pi;
    }
    //button interactions
    menuInteraction(posX,posY,sbg);


    if (beanPosY>=330){
        force=1;
    }
    beanPosY-=force;
    force-=gravity;
}

public int getID(){
    return 0;
}

private void menuInteraction(int posX, int posY, StateBasedGame sbg){
    //play button
    float startXDist=posX-(startPosX+50);
    float startYDist=(480-posY)-(startPosY+50);
    float startDist=(float) Math.sqrt((startXDist*startXDist)+(startYDist*startYDist));
    if(startDist<=50){
        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            sbg.enterState(1);
        }
    }

    //quit button
    float quitXDist=posX-(quitPosX+50);
    float quitYDist=(480-posY)-(quitPosY+50);
    float quitDist=(float) Math.sqrt((quitXDist*quitXDist)+(quitYDist*quitYDist));
    if(quitDist<=50){
        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

edit: The code above now creates an object within the 'init()' method which calls upon the 'Sound' class and its method 'playBackGround()'. The code for the Sound class is given in the answer below from JavaNewb.

edit: The errors produced by this code are as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javagame.Sound.run(Sound.java:45)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Final point, i have tried things such as the LWJGL libraries, i can't make sense of them. Also i realize how much I'm asking as I'm basically asking for someone to code this into my game which i wish i didn't have to do but i don't know how else to solve my problem without posting it on here.

PS. Its not like i haven't tried to do this myself, so don't be a pain and say I've made no effort

Comment: is there any error exception or the sound just don't play?

Comment: If you're serious about game development then you should look into finding the right framework/library that will take care of the low level stuff for you (such as playing sounds). Once you find a framework that suits your needs, you can focus on actually creating your game instead of reinventing wheels.

Comment: @damo - Do you have any suggestions for a framework?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do and which platform(s) you're targeting. I use [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) for Android games (though, it _is_ cross-platform). Using libgdx as an example, the framework doesn't require me to [put much effort into playing sounds](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AudioSound).

Comment: I'm not trying to be a "pain", and I'm certainly not going to accuse you of "making no effort", but I would highly recommend that you start off with some introductory Java material, such as Deitel's Java How to Program, so that you can have a better understanding of the code that you're looking at, and the basics of object oriented programming in general.

To actually answer your question, you've created a method that will play a sound clip, but you don't actually call that method anywhere during the intialization or rendering of your menu.  You'll need to call it for it to actually execute.

Comment: In addition to @LJ2's good advice, it's also good practice when you have a problem to create the simplest possible case to test your code. In this case, you could create a simple program that _only plays a sound_ when it's run, and that way you can test to make sure it works in the simple case before trying to figure out what's wrong in the larger case. (However, LJ2 already found your problem—you never call the `sound` method.)

Comment: @LJ2 - You should post your comment as an answer. You did after all find the bug in his code (not calling `sound`).

Comment: Actually I'm afraid that's not a bug, i removed where i called it from because errors were produced, I'm not that bad at java :P Good spot though

Comment: o yeah, also i always try to implement code i find in both a separate java program and within my game

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;

public class Sound implements Runnable
{
    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    public Sound()
    {
        this.start();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(running)
            return;
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        this.running = true;
        this.thread.start();
    }

    //
    private boolean playSong = false;
    private AudioInputStream inputStream;
    private String url;
    private Clip clip;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            if(inputStream == null && playSong)
            {
                this.playSong = false;
                try
                {
                    this.inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResource(url));
                    this.clip.open(inputStream);
                    this.clip.loop(10);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void playBackGround(String string) // call to play .wav file
    {
        if(this.clip != null)
        {
            this.clip.stop();
            this.clip.close();
        }
        try
        {
            this.clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        url = string + ".wav";
        this.playSong = true;
        this.inputStream = null;
    }

    public void disposeSound()
    {
        if(this.clip != null)
        {
            this.clip.stop();
            this.clip.close();
        }
        this.clip = null;
        this.playSong = false;
        this.inputStream = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've edited my code to implement what you've given me and put it in the original question. I'm afraid no sound is produced though, no errors are produced in run time but the IDE picks up on a few things when error checking which ill quote in comments on my code

Comment: right the problem is your class needs to implements Runnable... public class Sound implements Runnable

Comment: the above code is a class on its own seperate from your class. Just create an instance of this class in main and call the "playBackGround" method

Comment: just to be clear you need to create a new java class file and copy past the above code into it.

Comment: I understood thanks :) I'm having some problems still though, ill edit my question

Comment: Also I've just noticed that your Sound class concatenates ".wav" onto the end of the string given. Fixing this by calling playBackGround("res/doxx") doesn't change the errors produced at all. Also line 45 where the error is pointed out (by the console) in the Sound class is the line "this.inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResource(url));"

Comment: Final point, these imports within the Sound class aren't used   "import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;" not that this sound affect anything but i thought i should make sure the whole picture is there

Comment: this is odd, i dont get an error on line 45... but there were some imports not used. if there is an error on line 45 its maybe because your class name is not "Sound" because the code uses Sound.class.getResource(url) this is referring to the class that your in... Ex: MYClassName.class.getResource(url)

Comment: Well its named Sound.java how could i make it Sound.class ? Or is that not what you're getting at? I thought those were compiled by eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to create an AudioInputStream from a null URL. Make sure that url is not null, make sure that you reference a correct file.